# Is a document a sentence in a text file?

Tags: python, nlp, information-retrieval

For example, when calculating generality discount for a word in a corpus, one formula is log(N/n), where N is the number of documents in a corpus and n is the number documents that contains the word.

Is a document a string that ends with a new line?

Comment: Depends on what you want to call a document. It sounds more like you're describing a paragraph.

Comment: ok! So people use the word loosely. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your talking about Vector Space Modeling. See the [text analysis group's definition of Vector space model procedure](http://cogsys.imm.dtu.dk/thor/projects/multimedia/textmining/node5.html). This is a three-step process; the second stage indexes and weights words so as to improve the likelihood of retrieving the document relevant to the searcher. Many words are considered non-significant (e.g. in English: "a", "the", "an") and these are ignored for the purposes of this second stage. The formula you mentioned frequently shows up in this stage of the process. With regards to what is a document in this context: the entire document is transformed into a "document vector" which describes the salient contents of the document; think of this process as if librarian describing a book with a brief abstract. In other words, the document is the entire text, book, webpage that has been "vectorized" -- it isn't a single line delineated by newline.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on what you're calling a "document".

To me it sounds like you're describing a paragraph within a document. It *could* be a document, but then you'd have to identify "documents" by the full text and some sort of offset within that document, and feed the documents in appropriately.